# Will elementary OS run on a 32bit MacBook?

Tags: macbook

I have an old MacBook Core Duo, and I would like to run elementary OS exclusively on it.  Where do I get an 32 bit version (for Mac) of elementary OS?

Answer (score 0):

Elementary OS Loki doesn’t have 32bit release - there’s only 64bit.

However, Elementary OS Freya had 32bit version. If You really want to install elementary, You can try Freya, but it’s an old version.